# Call a public void routine in Android Studio Dolphin

Tags: java, android, methods, void, public

```
> package com.example.mytest;
> import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
> 
> import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> 
> import java.util.Arrays;
> import java.util.Date;
> import java.util.Locale;
> 
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>    @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     }
> 
> PrintScreen();
>  
> public void PrintScreen() {
> System.out.println("This is a test");    
>     }
> }
```

How can I call the public void method PrintScreen() in MainActivity (Android Studio Dolphin). It does not accept the code above. Thank

Comment: Call it in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do. Call `PrintScreen();` in onCreate

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PrintScreen();
 }
 
  
 public void PrintScreen() {
 System.out.println("This is a test");    
     }
 }
```